# Char variable behavior in C program

Tags: c, char, typedef

I wrote a sudoku solver program with function which checks if it is leagal to set a value in a specific location:

```
typedef int cell;
typedef char value;
typedef value sudokuGrid[GRID_SIZE]; // GRID_SIZE is 81


int isLegal (sudokuGrid game, cell location,value candidateDigit);
```

I also wrote a function to test isLegal function giving it a sudoku puzzle and once the solution is calculated checking if all set values are correct:

```
static void testIsLegal(){
   int i, solution;
   int mid_result, result;

   sudokuGrid testGrid = {
      '6','4','.','.','.','.','8','1','7',
      '1','7','.','8','6','.','2','.','4',
      '.','.','.','.','.','.','.','9','6',
      '.','8','.','.','9','6','.','.','.',
      '.','6','.','3','.','1','.','2','.',
      '.','.','.','2','5','.','.','6','.',
      '8','2','.','.','.','.','.','.','.',
      '3','.','7','.','1','8','.','4','2',
      '4','5','1','.','.','.','.','8','3'
   };


   printf("Testing isLegal() function ............\n");

   result = TRUE;


   solution = hasSolution(testGrid);
   showGame(testGrid);

   int f = isLegal(testGrid,78,'9');
   printf("isLegal(testGrid,78,9) = %d\n\n",f);


   i = 0;
   result = TRUE;
   value cellValue;
   if (solution){
      while ((result == TRUE) && (i < GRID_SIZE)){
         cellValue = testGrid[i];
         testGrid[i] = EMPTY_VALUE;
         printf("isLegal(testGrid,%d,%c) = %d\n",i,cellValue,isLegal(testGrid,i,cellValue));
         result = result && isLegal(testGrid,i,cellValue);
         testGrid[i] = cellValue;
         i++;
      }
    }
    if (result)
         printf("\t\t\t\t\t [OK]\n");
      else
         printf("\t\t\t\t\t[NOK]\n");
}
```

The result of executing this function with a wrong result is:

```
6 4 2   5 3 9   8 1 7
1 7 5   8 6 2   2 3 4
9 3 8   1 4 7   5 9 6

2 8 3   7 9 6   1 7 5
5 6 4   3 8 1   3 2 8
7 1 9   2 5 4   4 6 9

8 2 6   4 2 3   6 5 1
3 9 7   6 1 8   7 4 2
4 5 1   9 7 5   9 8 3
```

There are many mistakes here but I mentioned the both 9-s in the last line (possitions 75 and 78). Performed a manual check for isLegal(testGrid,78,'9') which returns FALSE, but when I use a loop isLegal(testGrid,i,cellValue) returns TRUE all the time:

```
isLegal(testGrid,78,9) = 0

isLegal(testGrid,0,6) = 1
isLegal(testGrid,1,4) = 1
isLegal(testGrid,2,2) = 1
isLegal(testGrid,3,5) = 1
.....
isLegal(testGrid,78,9) = 1
isLegal(testGrid,79,8) = 1
isLegal(testGrid,80,3) = 1
```

My question is why when I use char variable in ' ' quotes (isLegal(testGrid,78,'9') from the code) it shows the correct result, but not when I use cellValue variable?
How can this be fixed?

Thank you!

Adding additional information:

```
#define MIN_VALUE '1'
#define MAX_VALUE '9'
#define EMPTY_VALUE '.'
#define NUM_VALUES (MAX_VALUE - MIN_VALUE + 1)
#define GRID_SIZE (NUM_VALUES * NUM_VALUES)
#define MAX_CELL (GRID_SIZE - 1)

#define TRUE    1
#define FALSE   0

#define MINI_SQUARE_SIZE        3
#define SQUARE_SIZE             9

typedef int cell;
typedef char value;
typedef value sudokuGrid[GRID_SIZE];
```

isLegal function:

```
int isLegal (sudokuGrid game, cell location,value candidateDigit){
   assert (location >= 0);
   assert (location <= GRID_SIZE);

   assert (candidateDigit >= MIN_VALUE);
   assert (candidateDigit <= MAX_VALUE);

   return (isLegalLine(game,location,candidateDigit) &&
            isLegalColumn(game,location,candidateDigit) &&
            isLegalSquare(game,location,candidateDigit));
}




static int isLegalLine(sudokuGrid game, cell location,value candidateDigit){
   assert (location >= 0);
   assert (location <= GRID_SIZE);

   assert (candidateDigit >= MIN_VALUE);
   assert (candidateDigit <= MAX_VALUE);


   int result, mid_result;
   int i;
   int lineNumber = location / SQUARE_SIZE;

   result = TRUE;

   for (i = 0; i < GRID_SIZE; i++){
      if (( i / SQUARE_SIZE ) == lineNumber){
         if ( game[i] != candidateDigit ){
            mid_result = TRUE;
         }
         else{
            mid_result = FALSE;
         }
         result = result && mid_result;
      }
   }

   return result;
}

static int isLegalColumn(sudokuGrid game, cell location,value candidateDigit){
   assert (location >= 0);
   assert (location <= GRID_SIZE);

   assert (candidateDigit >= MIN_VALUE);
   assert (candidateDigit <= MAX_VALUE);


   int result, mid_result;
   int i;
   int columnNumber = location % SQUARE_SIZE;

   result = TRUE;

   for (i = 0; i < GRID_SIZE; i++){
      if (( i % SQUARE_SIZE ) == columnNumber){
         if ( game[i] != candidateDigit )
             mid_result = TRUE;
         else
             mid_result = FALSE;
         result = result && mid_result;
      }
   }
   return result;
}

static int isLegalSquare(sudokuGrid game, cell location,value candidateDigit){
   assert (location >= 0);
   assert (location <= GRID_SIZE);

   assert (candidateDigit >= MIN_VALUE);
   assert (candidateDigit <= MAX_VALUE);


   int result, mid_result;
   int i;

   int lineNumber = location / SQUARE_SIZE;
   int columnNumber = location % SQUARE_SIZE;
//   int squareNumber;

   if ( lineNumber < MINI_SQUARE_SIZE){
      lineNumber = 0;
      if (columnNumber < MINI_SQUARE_SIZE){
      //   squareNumber = 1;
         columnNumber = 0;
      }
      else if (columnNumber < 2*MINI_SQUARE_SIZE){
      //   squareNumber = 2;
         columnNumber = MINI_SQUARE_SIZE;
      }
      else{
      //   squareNumber = 3;
         columnNumber = 2*MINI_SQUARE_SIZE;
      }
   }

   else if (lineNumber < 2*MINI_SQUARE_SIZE){
      lineNumber = MINI_SQUARE_SIZE;
      if (columnNumber < MINI_SQUARE_SIZE){
      //   squareNumber = 4;
         columnNumber = 0;
      }
      else if (columnNumber < 2*MINI_SQUARE_SIZE){
      //   squareNumber = 5;
         columnNumber = MINI_SQUARE_SIZE;
      }
      else{
      //   squareNumber = 6;
         columnNumber = 2*MINI_SQUARE_SIZE;
      }
   }

   else{
      lineNumber = 2*MINI_SQUARE_SIZE;
      if (columnNumber < MINI_SQUARE_SIZE){
      //   squareNumber = 7;
         columnNumber = 0;
      }
      else if (columnNumber < 2*MINI_SQUARE_SIZE){
      //   squareNumber = 8;
         columnNumber = MINI_SQUARE_SIZE;
      }
      else{
      //   squareNumber = 9;
         columnNumber = 2*MINI_SQUARE_SIZE;
      }
   }

   result = TRUE;

   int squareStartLocation = columnNumber + ( SQUARE_SIZE * lineNumber);
   int k = 0;
   int squareStartLocationLineEnd;



   while (k < MINI_SQUARE_SIZE){
      squareStartLocationLineEnd = squareStartLocation + MINI_SQUARE_SIZE;
      for (i = squareStartLocation; i < squareStartLocationLineEnd; i++){
         if (game[i] != candidateDigit)
            mid_result = TRUE;
         else
            mid_result = FALSE;
         result = result && mid_result;
      }
      k++;
      squareStartLocation += SQUARE_SIZE;
      result = result && mid_result;
  }



   return result;

}
```

Comment: `Please show function `isLegal`.

Comment: It might be clearer for you without the unnecessary types invented. Decide whether a cell will contain a numeric `9` or a character `'9'` and stick with it.

Comment: But cellValue is type char. When I change  result = result && isLegal(testGrid,i,cellValue) to result = result && isLegal(testGrid,i,cellValue + '0') assert complains: "Assertion `candidateDigit <= '9'' failed."

Comment: There isn't enough information here to indicate any problem.  Either `isLegal` is modifying the array or EMPTY_VALUE != '.'

Comment: You could ensure that `isLegal` doesn't affect the board: `int isLegal (const sudokuGrid game, cell location, value candidateDigit);`, and your debug output would be clearer with `'%c'` than `%c` (it looks like you're showing codepoints rather than character values).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Parameter candidateDigit *will* be passed as a char type to isLegal().
It must be the loop context causing the function to always return TRUE, so you will need to:

- show us the code for isLegal()
- show us the value of EMPTY_VALUE

Update1: Thanks for the extra info. I plugged in your filled out "bad" data, set solution to TRUE, and the test stopped at position 14 with a failure (correctly as this position contains '2' and there is another in the same line). So it seems that your code is correct! At least as far as this test goes.

Test grid:

```
   sudokuGrid testGrid = {
      '6','4','2','5','3','9','8','1','7',
      '1','7','5','8','6','2','2','3','4',
      '9','3','8','1','4','7','5','9','6',
      '2','8','3','7','9','6','1','7','5',
      '5','6','4','3','8','1','3','2','8',
      '7','1','9','2','5','4','4','6','9',
      '8','2','6','4','2','3','6','5','1',
      '3','9','7','6','1','8','7','4','2',
      '4','5','1','9','7','5','9','8','3'
   };
```

Test output:

```
isLegal(testGrid,78,9) = 0

isLegal(testGrid,0,6) = 1
isLegal(testGrid,1,4) = 1
isLegal(testGrid,2,2) = 1
isLegal(testGrid,3,5) = 1
isLegal(testGrid,4,3) = 1
isLegal(testGrid,5,9) = 1
isLegal(testGrid,6,8) = 1
isLegal(testGrid,7,1) = 1
isLegal(testGrid,8,7) = 1
isLegal(testGrid,9,1) = 1
isLegal(testGrid,10,7) = 1
isLegal(testGrid,11,5) = 1
isLegal(testGrid,12,8) = 1
isLegal(testGrid,13,6) = 1
isLegal(testGrid,14,2) = 0
                    [NOK]
```

NB Only other code changes I made were to move isLegal() below the functions that it calls (to avoid default promotion of return types) and to comment out calls to hasSolution() and showGrid().

Comment: #define EMPTY_VALUE '.'

Comment: Can I add a code in multi-line format as a comment?

Comment: @maimun4itu see my answer edits above; I compiled your code, using gcc on linux, and it correctly identified first illegal value. Also reviewing your code, it appears correct although I just checked the main areas where it might fail.

Comment: Very strange! I moved isLegal below the functions it uses too. Also displayed all values that cellValue receives and they are chars between '1' and '9' just as they should be. But still testIsLegal returns true for all the values :(

Comment: I made a separate program including only isLegal and testIslegal functions and just as you said- it exits at possition 14. Seems that a correct function is used in uncorrect way in my full program. Will checkeverything once again. Thanks for your help!

Comment: I am using Linux and gcc too. 
It works now. 
It was all my mistake - as I said I had 2 isLegal functions- one working and one not.  My idea was to use testIsLegal to find out if the sudoku solution is correct. And I expected to receive [OK] for the working isLegal and [NOK] for the wrong isLegal function. But I used the sudoku solution calculated from these isLegal functions (not a filled in grids for which I know if they should return true or false). So the wrong calculated sudoku solution goes through the wrong isLegal function in the test and of course passes it.

Comment: So, it was all ok from the very beggining, just used in a wrong way.
Thank you for your help anyway, as your comments helped me find what I did wrong!

Comment: Cool, just needed another pair of eyes :) ... I have done this sort of thing, plugged in alternative versions of methods, and find that "memo to self" type comments help me to keep track.

Answer (score 2):

Think a little bit about what this:

```
testGrid[i] = EMPTY_VALUE;
```

will do to isLegal() in the next line:

```
printf("isLegal(testGrid,%d,%c) = %d\n",i,cellValue,isLegal(testGrid,i,cellValue));
```

Maybe this does something in isLegal() what you don't want

Comment: But you don't clear the cell before calling `int f = isLegal(testGrid,78,'9');
`.

Answer (score 0):

If you do `char a = 9`, you are making that `a` have an ASCII value.
For example:
`char letter = 80;` is equivalent to `char letter = 'P';`

Comment: Maybe that is the reason. Have to find a way to set it to the value I want. Just adding quotes does not work.

Comment: I did'n get the point... you sad that when you use quotes the code works, but now you are saying that it does'nt works.

Comment: It works when I use quotes like '9', but not if I use them with a variable: cellValue = 'testGrid[i]' does not work, which is normal I guess because I set the possible values in the grid between MIN_VALUE '1' and MAX_VALUE '9'  (which are ints between 49 and 57). But in this case aren't the possible testGrid[i] values again between '1' and '9'?

Comment: I understand, but I have no idea of what to do.